# Detect OS language

Tags: vb.net

I need to detect the OS system where my VB.net application runs, in order to know how the Program Files folder is called on the system itself. I'm trying to use what follows:

```
Select Case Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
    Case "zh-CN"
        Label21.Text = "Program Files"
    Case "CS-CZ"
        Label21.Text = "Program Files"
    Case "da-DK"
        Label21.Text = "Programmer"
    Case "nl-NL"
        Label21.Text = "Program Files"
    Case "en-US"
        Label21.Text = "Program Files"
    Case "fr-FR"
        Label21.Text = "Programmes"
    Case "de-DE"
        Label21.Text = "Programme"
    Case "it-IT"
        Label21.Text = "Programmi"
    Case "NB-NO"
        Label21.Text = "Programfiler"
    Case "pl-PL"
        Label21.Text = "Program Files"
    Case "PT-BR"
        Label21.Text = "Arquivos de Programas"
    Case "PT-PT"
        Label21.Text = "Arquivos de Programas"
    Case "ro-RO"
        Label21.Text = "Fisiere Program"
    Case "ru-RU"
        Label21.Text = "Program Files"
    Case "es-ES"
        Label21.Text = "Archivos de programa"
    Case "SV-SE"
        Label21.Text = "Program"
End Select
```

This task seems not to work, because nothing gets written on the Label21. Where am I doing wrong? Thanks all are gonna answer me.
Best regards

Comment: You don't need to: [Environment.GetFolderPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath) => [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder)

Comment: .,.. `.ProgramFiles` or `.ProgramFilesX86`

Comment: The folder is always called Program Files. Explorer translates it for user language.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Private Culture As new System.Globalization.CultureInfo`
or say `Dim Culture As new System.Globalization.CultureInfo`
, once instantiated hten you can get the current culture

There you have many properties like:

```
Culture.EnglishName

Culture.Name

Culture.NativeName

Culture.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName
```